# Add extra dependency on war building

Tags: java, maven, maven-war-plugin

I have maven project with next modules: `app`, `app-impl`, `web`. I build  web with maven-war-plugin. Now `app-impl` depends on `app`. `web` depends on `app-impl`.

But `web` should depends only on `app`. By some magic maven-war-plugin should include `app-impl` in war. Could I do it without additional maven module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I absolutely agree with @Torsten, but maybe there is something valid in your request:

when using IDE to develop the project, you can require it to stop offering your *implementation* classes in code completion lists.

If this is your reason, just add both dependencies, and for the implementation one, specify `<scope>runtime</scope>`.
This ensures that:

- your `app` module get to classpath of javac, but `app-impl` does not
- both `app` and `app-impl` will be placed under `WEB-INF/lib/` in your war
- IDE (if properly implemented) will not offer you completions from `app-impl`

This definitely does not save you keystrokes, but gives you a better pom, carefully modelling the reality.

Comment: Runtime scope it was what I searching for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO having a dependency on `app` in `web` does not reflect the reality, as your web-application really depends on having an implementation of the interfaces I assume you have defined in `app`.

Consider having an alternative implementation in lets say `app-impl2`. How can maven possibly decide which implementation it should choose?

So having web depend on app-impl is to me the way to go and given the above setup also should work out of the box.